# How to compress gif image file

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I create 62 images. The size of all images is 4.24MB. One image size 70.1KB. I am creating gif file using below code but the size of gifimage is 41.1MB. How can I compress the size, because I used very low quality images.

```
  public void createGiffile()
        {
            string outputFilePath = @"C:\Attachment62.gif";
           string path = @"E:\saveimage\New folder";
            var images = Directory.GetFiles(path).OrderBy(c => c.Length).ToArray();

            this.progressBar1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { progressBar1.Maximum = images.Length; progressBar1.Step = 1; });         

            AnimatedGifEncoder es = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
            es.Start(outputFilePath);
            //  es.SetDelay(500);
            //-1:no repeat,0:always repeat
            es.SetRepeat(0);


            for (int i = 0, count = imageFilePaths.Length; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    string ss = "";
                }
                es.AddFrame(Image.FromFile(imageFilePaths[i]));

                this.progressBar1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { progressBar1.PerformStep(); });
            }
            es.Finish();
}
```

Comment: Try this: http://www.codelocker.net/10175/c-sharp-dot-net-compress-an-image-in-dot-net/

Comment: Why not use [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a56eddd3-d79b-48ac-8c8f-2db06ade77c3) Visual Studio add-in?

Comment: i am using 3.5 frame work is it working ?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz i have animated gif file , this code is not working for me

Comment: SUPPORTS
Visual Studio
2015, 2013, 2012, 15